# Problem in Achieving concurrency in Java 17

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, threadpool

I am having some products and these products have multiple attributes related to it.
BulkEditRequest class :

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Data
public class BulkEditRequest{

    private String productId;
    private String productNum;
    private  Map<String,AttributesResponse> attributeList;
}
```

AttributesResponse class looks like:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Data
public class AttributesResponse {
    private String attributeName;
    private String attributeValue;
    private String attributeType;
    private String attributeId;
    
    public AttributesResponse() {
        super();
    }
}
```

To keep it simple, there is a list of Products, where each product has a list of attributes. Based on the attributeType of each attribute, I have to make a post call to save the attributeValue by making a call to external API.

Note: The external API which I am using doesn't accepts a list of attributes, so I have to make one API call for one attribute.

My current implementation is very basic:

Iterate through the BulkProducts -> Iterate through each product -> collect the attributes into a list --> iterate through each attributeObj -> find attributeType -> make the API call based on attributeType.

(using forEach for all these loops).Below is the current code implementation :

```
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Service
public class ServiceImpl {

    private RestTemplate template;

    public ServiceImpl(RestTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void saveProductsInFlex(List<BulkEditRequest> attributesByProd) {

        for (BulkEditRequest singleProduct : attributesByProd) {
            String prodNum = singleProduct.getProductNum();

            List<AttributesResponse> attributeList = new ArrayList<AttributesResponse>(
                    singleProduct.getAttributeList().values());

            for (AttributesResponse attribute : attributeList) {

                if ("Price".equalsIgnoreCase(attribute.getAttributeType())) {

                    setProductPrice(singleProduct, attribute);

                } else if ("Identifier".equalsIgnoreCase(attribute.getAttributeType())) {

                    setProductIdentifier(singleProduct, attribute);

                } else if ("Attribute".equalsIgnoreCase(attribute.getAttributeType())) {

                    setProductAttribute(singleProduct, attribute);

                }

            }

        }

    }

    private void setProductPrice(BulkEditRequest singleProduct, AttributesResponse attributeResponse) {
        HttpEntity<UploadEntity> flexEntity = null;
        String uri = null;
        int productId = 0;
        String attribute = attributeResponse.getAttributeName();
        if (singleProduct != null) {
            uri = Constants.BASEURL + singleProduct.getProductNum() + Constants.PRICES;
            productId = Integer.parseInt(singleProduct.getProductNum());

        }
        try {
            UploadEntity entity = new UploadEntity();
            entity.setPrice(attributeResponse.getAttributeValue());
            entity.setUomID(1);
            entity.setCountryCode("US");
            flexEntity = new HttpEntity<>(entity);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = template.postForEntity(uri, flexEntity, String.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    private void setProductAttribute(BulkEditRequest singleProduct, AttributesResponse attributeResponse) {
        HttpEntity<UploadEntity> flexEntity = null;
        String attribute = attributeResponse.getAttributeName();
        String uri = null;
        int productId = 0;
        if (singleProduct != null) {
            uri = Constants.BASEURL + singleProduct.getProductNum() + Constants.ATTRIBUTES;
            productId = Integer.parseInt(singleProduct.getProductNum());
        }
        try {

            UploadEntity entity = new UploadEntity();

            entity.setAttributeId(attributeResponse.getAttributeId());
            flexEntity = new HttpEntity<>(entity);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = template.postForEntity(uri, flexEntity, String.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    private void setProductIdentifier(BulkEditRequest singleProduct, AttributesResponse attributeResponse) {
        HttpEntity<UploadEntity> flexEntity = null;
        String attribute = attributeResponse.getAttributeName();
        String uri = null;
        int productId = 0;
        if (singleProduct != null) {
            uri = Constants.BASEURL + singleProduct.getProductNum() + Constants.IDENTIFIERS;
            productId = Integer.parseInt(singleProduct.getProductNum());
        }

        try {
            UploadEntity entity = new UploadEntity();
            entity.setProductIdentifier(attributeResponse.getAttributeValue());
            flexEntity = new HttpEntity<>(entity);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = template.postForEntity(uri, flexEntity, String.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

}
```

The UploadEntity class looks like :

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UploadEntity {


    //Price
    private String price;

    private String countryCode;
    private String uomID;

    

    //Identifier

    private String productIdentifier;

    
    //Attribute

    private String attributeId;


}
```

This implementation takes a lot of time (considering 1 product has minimum of 50 attributes). Any suggestions on how I can make it concurrent would be really helpful.

Comment: you messed up the formatting. You can edit the question and fix it.

Comment: Can you please add some code? Anyway, you can collect the informations in a map or a list, using streams and their filters/iterators, then you can perform the API calls with a parallel stream on the map you created before.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have edited the code , plz review the code..and plz provide your insights on the same..

Comment: Up-voting. The author has complied with all criticisms.

Answer (score 1):

### Virtual threads

Sounds like a good use for the new [virtual threads](https://AttributesResponse) feature of [Java 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_21)+ arriving this month.

For each list of attributes to be processed, instantiate a `ExecutorService` based on virtual threads. Do that instantiation within try-with-resources syntax.

```
try (
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
) { … }
```

Define a class that implements `Runnable` or `Callable`, or define a lambda, as a task to process an attribute. Submit to the executor service as a task an instance per attribute.

Once that is working, you can similarly make the outer code concurrent. Instantiate another executor service based on virtual threads, and submit each product as a task. So now you have many products concurrently each processing its list of attributes concurrently.

Virtual threads are vastly cheaper than platform threads. So you can reasonably have a million virtual threads running.

### Example code

Here is a simple example app.

We define a `Product` [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) that contains a collection of `Attribute` record objects.

```
record Attribute( String id ) { }
record Product( int id , Collection < Attribute > attributes ) { }
```

We send each `Product` object off to a virtual thread. On that virtue thread, each of the `Attribute` objects within that `Product` is sent off to a virtual thread for submission to a web service.

The key point to understand is that  each call to [`ExecutorSerivce#submit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) does *not* [block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)). The task, here defined as a lambda, is sent un-executed to the executor service. The executor service manages the chore of handing that task (that lambda) to a virtual thread for eventual execution. The thread calling `submit` has long since moved on to other work.

**Beware:** Output from `System.out` does *not* necessarily appear chronologically when called across threads. If you care about the order, always include and study a timestamp (`Instant.now()`).

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class AttributeProcessor
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        AttributeProcessor app = new AttributeProcessor ( );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        List < Product > products = this.sampleData ( );
        try (
                ExecutorService executorServiceProducts = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
        )
        {
            for ( Product product : products )
            {
                executorServiceProducts.submit ( ( ) ->
                {
                    try (
                            ExecutorService executorServiceAttributes = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
                    )
                    {
                        for ( Attribute attribute : product.attributes ( ) )
                        {
                            executorServiceAttributes.submit ( ( ) ->
                            {
                                 try
                                {
                                    // Simulate long wait as we send off this attribute to a web service.
                                    Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMillis ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 300 , 1200 ) ) );
                                    System.out.println ( "DEBUG - Processed attribute " + attribute.id ( ) + " of product " + product.id ( ) + " at " + Instant.now ( ) );
                                }
                                catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
                             } );
                        }
                    }
                } );
            }
        }
    }

    private List < Product > sampleData ( )
    {
        return
                List.of (
                        new Product (
                                1 ,
                                List.of (
                                        new Attribute ( "A" ) ,
                                        new Attribute ( "B" ) ,
                                        new Attribute ( "C" )
                                )
                        ) ,
                        new Product (
                                2 ,
                                List.of (
                                        new Attribute ( "D" ) ,
                                        new Attribute ( "E" ) ,
                                        new Attribute ( "F" )
                                )
                        ) ,
                        new Product (
                                3 ,
                                List.of (
                                        new Attribute ( "X" ) ,
                                        new Attribute ( "Y" ) ,
                                        new Attribute ( "Z" )
                                )
                        )
                );
    }
}

record Attribute( String id ) { }

record Product( int id , Collection < Attribute > attributes ) { }
```

When run:

```
DEBUG - Processed attribute Z of product 3 at 2023-09-06T19:20:10.327374Z
DEBUG - Processed attribute Y of product 3 at 2023-09-06T19:20:10.327376Z
DEBUG - Processed attribute E of product 2 at 2023-09-06T19:20:10.455059Z
DEBUG - Processed attribute X of product 3 at 2023-09-06T19:20:10.491004Z
DEBUG - Processed attribute B of product 1 at 2023-09-06T19:20:10.795873Z
DEBUG - Processed attribute F of product 2 at 2023-09-06T19:20:10.969192Z
DEBUG - Processed attribute C of product 1 at 2023-09-06T19:20:11.072108Z
DEBUG - Processed attribute D of product 2 at 2023-09-06T19:20:11.072108Z
DEBUG - Processed attribute A of product 1 at 2023-09-06T19:20:11.154606Z
```

I have omitted the tough part: Graceful error handling. For one thing, in real work we would capture the `Future` returned by `ExecutorService#submit`, and process them to verify success. For another thing, we would need to account for time-outs on the web service calls.

### Java 17

In Java 17, you could do something similar to the code seen above. But Java 17 has only expensive platform threads, without any cheap virtual threads. So you would need to instantiate and re-use one or two executor services with a limited number of threads.

FYI, Java 21 is a [long-term support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version of Java, like Java 17.

Here is some example code using a single `ExecutorService` in Java 17.

Pass to `newFixedThreadPool` a number of threads appropriate to your machine.

Notice my slightly modified version of the boilerplate code given to you in [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) in method `shutdownAndAwaitTermination`. That boilerplate gracefully shuts down your executor service so that its backing pool of threads does not run indefinitely. We must write such a method because `ExecutorService` did not become [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) until Java 19.

```java
List < Product > products = this.sampleData ( );
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool ( 7 );
for ( Product product : products )
{
    for ( Attribute attribute : product.attributes ( ) )
    {
        executorService.submit ( ( ) ->
        {
            try
            {
                // Simulate long wait as we send off this attribute to a web service.
                Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMillis ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 300 , 1200 ) ) );
                System.out.println ( "DEBUG - Processed attribute " + attribute.id ( ) + " of product " + product.id ( ) + " at " + Instant.now ( ) );
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
        } );
    }
}
this.shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( executorService );
```

```java
private void shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( final ExecutorService executorService )
{
    executorService.shutdown ( ); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
    try
    {
        // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate.
        if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination ( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
        {
            executorService.shutdownNow ( ); // Cancel currently executing tasks.
            // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled.
            if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination ( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
                System.err.println ( "Executor service did not terminate." + Instant.now ( ) );
        }
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException ex )
    {
        executorService.shutdownNow ( );  // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
        Thread.currentThread ( ).interrupt ( );  // Preserve interrupt status
    }
}
```